# Manually call Hibernate URL validator in spring-boot

Tags: spring, hibernate, validation, hibernate-mapping, hibernate-validator

I am using spring-boot 1.4.0 and hibernate-validator 5.2.0. I have a model which contains custom validator inside the custom validator i want to check whether the property value is a valid URL for that i need to call [URLValidator](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-validator/blob/master/engine/src/main/java/org/hibernate/validator/internal/constraintvalidators/hv/URLValidator.java) in hibernate but no luck.Could anyone please guide me to resolve this issue

**CustomValidator.java**

```
@Component
public class BookValidator extends GenericValidator<Book,    ConstraintValidatorContext> implements ConstraintValidator<ValidBooks,  List<Book>> {


public BookValidator() {
    addValidators();
}

private void addValidators() {
 getValidators().add((book, context) -> {
        boolean isValid = book.getUrl(); //here i want to check against Hibernate URL validator 
        if (!isValid) {
            context.disableDefaultConstraintViolation();
            context
                    .buildConstraintViolationWithTemplate("Book URL should be valid!")
                    .addConstraintViolation();
        }
        return isValid;
    });
}
@Override
public void initialize(ValidBooks constraintAnnotation) {
}
}
```

How can i check whether the URL is a valid one 
**boolean isValid = book.getUrl();** using hibernate [URLValidator](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-validator/blob/master/engine/src/main/java/org/hibernate/validator/internal/constraintvalidators/hv/URLValidator.java)?

Answer (score 2):

This works:

```
AnnotationDescriptor<URL> descriptor = new AnnotationDescriptor<URL>( URL.class ); 
URL url = AnnotationFactory.create(descriptor);
URLValidator urlValidator = new URLValidator();
urlValidator.initialize(url);

boolean isValid = urlValidator.isValid(book.getUrl(), context);
```